# Do Java Jframe checkboxes retain user input?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have a basic question that I need answering please. I have code that is based around checkboxes and does specific activities to each one. My question is do Java Jfame checkboxes retain the state that the user leaves it in (e.g. checked or unchecked) after the program is closed, and load into that state the next time the program is opened? Thank you in advance.

P.S. If it does not save, then how can I make it save? Are there other alternates or...?

Comment: -1, Try it. Run you program, close the program and restart the program. What happens?

Comment: I am using eclipse, so I did not know if it was just exclusive to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not.  If you don't explicitly save something from one instance of a program running, then it will not be saved.